In-memory data structure or collection in C# that exhibits peek and lock behavior like AWS SQS or Azure Service Bus Queues
I have a requirement to dequeue messages from cloud queue and then process them. However, for each worker instance, we want to let the worker define how many messages it can comfortably process concurrently. For example, there might be a worker that can process up to 100 messages from queue concurrently, another might just process 10 messages concurrently. So we want the worker instance to always process that many messages provided the queue has messages so the worker capacity is fully utilized.
We are trying to solve this in our code using Channels as below:
I use a Channel to connect the producer and consumer. And then a concurrent dictionary to keep track of the consumer tasks so it does not go beyond specified number (100 in below case). I tried searching for other data structures but none gives any behavior like peek and lock so the message is picked by one consumer, processed and then deleted later. During this time, the message should not be available to other consumers.
Wanted to know if there is a better data structure available to solve this problem than what I am currently using.
Few questions and comments about the code:

The ProduceAsync function should dequeue more messages and write to channel if there are less than 100 (configurable per worker) messages currently being processed concurrently. Otherwise it should just wait for space to be available in the channel.
The ConsumeAsync method currently reads one message from the channel and calls the ProcessMessageAsync method in a fire-and-forget manner leading to all messages being processed concurrently. To remove this fire-and-forget I would need to use another Task list to do await Task.WhenAll which would be additional list maintenance. I am open to suggestions on this to improve this further if I can do it somehow using the current ConucurrentDictionary that is storing the Tasks already.


internal class Program
{
    static readonly Random random = new Random();
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task> messageProcessingTasksMap =
 new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task>();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            cts.Cancel();
        };

        var channel = Channel.CreateBounded<string>(new BoundedChannelOptions(100)
        {
            SingleReader = true,
            SingleWriter = true,
            AllowSynchronousContinuations = false
        });

        var program = new Program();
        var statsTask = program.TaskStatsAsync(channel.Reader, cts.Token);
        var producerTask = program.ProduceAsyc(channel.Writer, cts.Token);
        var consumerTask = program.ConsumeAsync(channel.Reader, cts.Token);

        await Task.WhenAll(statsTask, producerTask, consumerTask);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private async Task ProduceAsyc(ChannelWriter<string> channelWriter,
 CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // 100 will come from config and will be different for
            // different workers
            if (messageProcessingTasksMap.Count < 100)  
            {
                int messagesToDequeue = 100 - messageProcessingTasksMap.Count;
                if (messagesToDequeue > 10)
                {
                    messagesToDequeue = 10;
                }
        
                for (int i = 0; i < messagesToDequeue; i++)
                {
                    // In actual scenario, this will dequeue messages
                    // from cloud queue and write to channel
                    await channelWriter.WriteAsync($"Message-{i}");
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Stopping producer. Marking channel complete");
        channelWriter.Complete();
        Console.WriteLine("Producer stopped...");
    }

    private async Task ConsumeAsync(ChannelReader<string> channelReader,
 CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (await channelReader.WaitToReadAsync())
        {
            while (messageProcessingTasksMap.Count < 100 &&
 channelReader.TryRead(out var message))
            {
                var taskId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                messageProcessingTasksMap.TryAdd(taskId,
 ProcessMessageAsync(message, taskId));
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Stopping consumer...");
        Console.WriteLine($"Channel Count: {channelReader.Count}");
    }

    private async Task ProcessMessageAsync(string message, string taskId)
    {
        // Add delay to simulate some work
        await Task.Delay(random.Next(100, 300));
        messageProcessingTasksMap.Remove(taskId, out var _);
    }

    private async Task TaskStatsAsync(ChannelReader<string> channelReader,
 CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"Number of tasks being processed: {messageProcessingTasksMap.Count}" +
                $", Channel Count: {channelReader.Count}");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Exiting Stats Task");
    }
}


Regarding limiting the concurrency, can't you use BoundedChannelOptions to do that? Otherwise, for more complicated scenarios have you looked into the DataFlow library?

Yes I tried with BoundedChannelOptions but in my case I don't want to dequeue from the cloud queue (AWS SQS) unless I know this worker has capacity to process more messages. I can dequeue and just write which will eventually write when the space becomes available. But then instead of dequeing and waiting for space it would be good to let other workers dequeue and process if they have space already available. And I explored DataFLow (BufferBlock) too and it is same issue. After I read from BufferBlock/Channel it's deleted and then the Count is no more reliable to limit concurrency.

"a worker that can process up to 100 messages from queue concurrently" -- In your example the worker (ConsumeAsync) processes one message at a time, sequentially. Could you explain, and ideally demonstrate, how are you planning to implement the concurrent processing? I would also add that demonstrating the problem, mixed with your idea about how to solve it, makes things more difficult to us. It's hard to understand where the problem ends and where your attempted solution begins. Presenting your problem in its purest form, without ConcurrentDictionarys and stuff,  would be preferable.

@TheodorZoulias The below line calls the ProcessMessageAsync function which processes the message. It's called without await and hence the next message from channel would be picked up and then again ProcessMessageAsync will be called. And so on for each message in the channel. This leads to all the messages in the channel getting processed concurrently.
messageProcessingTasksMap.TryAdd(taskId, ProcessMessageAsync(message, taskId));

I will edit the code to add line breaks. Earlier I used to get a Preview button but could not find it while posting today.

"It's called without await" -- Ah, so the tasks created by the ProcessMessageAsync are fire-and-forget. That's a bad idea in general. How do you know when the worker has completed processing the consumed messages? You don't. I would suggest to mention/clarify in the question the fire-and-forget aspect of the processing, and whether you are satisfied by it, or you are open for ideas to improve it.

The preview of the formatted question is positioned below the text editor. The preview is always visible. No preview button exists, because it's not needed.

Thank you @TheodorZoulias. I have edited my post to include clarifications regarding the methods and also was able to view the Preview by scrolling down. Thank you!

@vrcks you can simplify your code a lot by using Parallel.ForEachAsycn with the IAsyncEnumerable returned by ChannelReader.ReadAllAsync and a specific DOP to specify the workers. If you want to dequeue from AWS only if a "worker" is available, set the bounded channel size to 1, not 100. Increase the bound to allow caching of items. There's no need for the dictionary or the manual count.

@vrcks cloud queues allow you to retrieve multiple items at a time too.

@vrcks does the order matter? Parallel.ForEachAsync doesn't guarantee the order of execution. If one message takes longer than others, its processing may complete after previous ones.

@PanagiotisKanavos Order does not strictly matter but whatever gets dequeued from the cloud queue first should get queued first approximately. Since cloud queues do not guarantee strict FIFO with standard queues.

@vrcks that's a matter of (cloud) queue configuration and as far as I remember, SQS delivers items in the order it sees them. Things become tricky with "retries" when older messages start reappearing. In any case, check the answer that shows how to combine channels for both buffering and concurrent operation. I omitted a lot of the real details behind SQS, monitoring and error/result handling. In this SO question I show how a Result<TMsg,TError> type can be used

@vrcks you can also use .NET's recent OpenTelemetry support through Activity/ActivitySource to monitor and track messages, from the queue all the way to the end, even if you don't use OTEL. You can pass an ActivityContext between processing steps as part of an Envelope<TMessage,TResult> instead of just a single message.

@PanagiotisKanavos Problem with data flow blocks is I will have to dequeue from cloud queue and block till space is available. I would not want to delay the message as soon as it's dequeued and only way to ensure is to know if I have the capacity to process and only dequeue as per the capacity. And yes we do use OpenTelemetry and also link our worker traces to publishers (usually API services) using linking.

@vrcks why do you say that? You can set an input buffer capacity that's large enough to keep the workers busy without flooding memory and pause if the input buffer is full. You can fiddle with the capacity to ensure messages don't have to wait too much, and even lower it to 1 if you want throttling without buffering

@vrcks to know if I have the capacity the block/channels knows that when you call await block.SendAsync or await writer.SendAsync. In many cases there's no reason to have a capacity larger than 1. In fact, Go channels have capacity =1 by default. A larger capacity can smooth variability but won't make the workers run faster

@vrcks you can modify the code I posted to do the same. Set the bounded capacity to 1 but keep MaxNumberOfMessages at 10. The Consumer method already processes up to 10 messages concurrently. With capacity=1 you ensure you won't call SQS again until the previous batch has finished. You'll get a delay only if the next SQS call can't get 10 messages in the wait timeout. You can smooth this if you increase capacity to eg 2 or 3, so you can ask for the next batch while the last 2-3 messages are processed.

Here is a suggestion that is radically different from what you are doing in the question. There are no channels, producers or concurrent dictionaries. Basically you can relegate all the throttling and processing to the Parallel.ForEachAsync API (.NET 6). This method accepts a sequence of elements (synchronous or asynchronous sequence), and invokes an asynchronous action for each element in the sequence. The elements are retrieved from the sequence automatically one by one, whenever there is available parallelism for processing another element, according to the MaxDegreeOfParallelism policy.
The last ingredient in the solution is to implement the source sequence as an iterator, that dequeues messages from the cloud and yields them one by one:
async IAsyncEnumerable<string> Iterator(
    [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Here, in actual scenario, a message from cloud will be dequeued.
        // The cancellationToken can be passed to the dequeuing API,
        // for more responsive cancellation.
        string message = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        yield return message;
    }
}

CancellationTokenSource cts = new();

ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10,
    CancellationToken = cts.Token
};

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(Iterator(), parallelOptions, async (message, ct) =>
{
    await ProcessMessageAsync(message, ct);
});

With this approach you could say that the Iterator plays the role of the producer.

Thank you for this approach. I will try this out with my sample prototype solution. However, AWS SQS queue allows to dequeue 10 messages at once and I am unclear how the Iterator would behave in this case. Dequeuing just one every time from AWS SQS would be inefficient. I will test this out.

@vrcks if the cloud API gives you 10 messages at once, you can simply yield them one by one in a loop. Be aware that by fetching multiple messages from the cloud and yielding them individually, it becomes possible to lose messages, in case the Parallel.ForEachAsync completes prematurely because of an exception or cancellation. It might be safer to yield all fetched messages as a batch, by converting the return type of the Iterator to IAsyncEnumerable<string[]>.

You can use ChannelReader.ReadAllAsync to asynchronously read the messages in a channel as an IAsyncEnumerable<> and use Parallel.ForEachAsync to process them concurrently using a specific number of workers. There's no need for manual counting or blocking.
On top of that you can retrieve multiple messages from either AWS SQS or Azure Queues. If you set the channel's bound to the batch size, you can retrieve one batch at a time and keep all workers active.
The code becomes cleaner and easier to compose if each method in a pipeline consumes a ChannelWriter and returns a ChannelReader. The final code can look as simple as :
await sqsClient.ReceiveFromQueue(qUrl,10,cts.Token)
               .ProcessMessages(10,cts.Token)
               .DeleteMessages(sqsClient,qUrl,cts.Token);

In the following example, the SQS code was borrowed from the SQS .NET Receive example, with a few parts left to the reader. The methods are static extension methods, allowing the entire pipeline to be constructed in a fluent way
public static ChannelReader<Message> ReceiveFromQueue(this AmazonSqsClient sqsClient, string qUrl,
    int batch,CancellationToken token)
{
     Channel<Message> _channel=Channel.CreateBounded(batch);
     var writer=_channel.Writer;

     _ = Task.Run(()=>{
         while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
         {
           var req=new ReceiveMessageRequest{
                           QueueUrl=qUrl,
                           MaxNumberOfMessages=batch,
                           ...};
           var response=await sqsClient.ReceiveMessageAsync(req);
           foreach(var msg in response.Messages)
           {
               await _writer.WriteAsync(msg);
           }
        }
     })
     //Propagate catastrophic errors
     .ContinueWith(t=>writer.TryComplete(t.Exception));
    return _channel.Reader;
}

The consumer accepts the reader and process the messages concurrently with Parallel.ForEachAsync. The method itself returns the Messages in another channel so a later step can confirm them :
public static ChannelReader<Message> ProcessMessages(this ChannelReader<Message>, 
    int dop, CancellationToken token)
{
     Channel<Message> _channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded();
     var writer=_channel.Writer;
     
     var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = dop};

     _ = Parallel.ForEachAsync(reader.ReadAllAsync(token), options,
            async (msg,ct)=>{
                await ProcessMessage(msg,ct);
                await writer.WriteAsync(msg);
            }
          ).ContinueWith(t=>_writer.TryComplete(t.Exception);

     return _channel.Reader;
}

Finally, DeleteMessages deletes the processed messages. This time there's no need to return anything  :
public static async Task ProcessMessages(this ChannelReader<Message>, 
    AmazonSqsClient sqsClient, string qUrl, CancellationToken token)
{
     Channel<Message> _channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded();
     var writer=_channel.Writer;
     
     var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = dop};

     await foreach (var msg in reader.ReadAllAsync(token))
     {
         await sqsClient.DeleteMessageAsync(qUrl,msg.ReceiptHandle);
     };
}

All the methods can be combined fluently :
var cts=new CancellationTokenSource();

var qUrl=".....";

await sqsClient.ReceiveFromQueue(qUrl,10,cts.Token)
               .ProcessMessages(10,cts.Token)
               .DeleteMessages(sqsClient,qUrl,cts.Token);

A lot of variations can be made to this. The upper limit of MaxNumberOfMessages is 10. A larger channel bound can be used to buffer more messages while still retrieving 10 at a time :
public static ChannelReader<Message> ReceiveFromQueue(string qUrl,
    int batch,CancellationToken token)
{
...
           var req=new ReceiveMessageRequest{
                           QueueUrl=qUrl,
                           MaxNumberOfMessages=batch>10?10:batch,
                           ...};
...
}

ProcessMessages can propagate only successful messages for deletion, assuming the inner ProcessMessage handles and logs errors. This would allow reprocessing of those messages later :
public static ChannelReader<Message> ProcessMessages(this ChannelReader<Message>, 
    int dop, CancellationToken token)
{
     Channel<Message> _channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded();
     var writer=_channel.Writer;

     var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = dop};

     _ = Parallel.ForEachAsync(reader.ReadAllAsync(token), options,
            async (msg,ct)=>{
                if(await ProcessMessage(msg,ct))
                {
                    await writer.WriteAsync(msg);
                }
            }
          ).ContinueWith(t=>_writer.TryComplete(t.Exception);

     return _channel.Reader;
}

